# Samsung Galaxy GT s7562 WiFi stuck at "Turning On"

Tags: wi-fi, system-freeze, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

The WiFi on my Samsung Galaxy S Duos GT s7562 froze. It shows "TURNING ON" and stays forever like that.

- I tried a hard reset. Still not working.
- I tried some dialer codes (like `*#*#526#*#*`) to restart the WiFi drivers, etc. and the codes are not working. It's just dialing.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: It stays same even after 2 or 3 hard resets.

Comment: I tried the previos mentioned steps from this page ->   http://techblogpremium.com/samsung-galaxy-s-duos-s7562-wifi-fix-method/

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78599/samsung-galaxy-gt-s7562-wifi-freeze-showing-turining-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WiFi hardware was faulty. (This is a common issue)
The WiFi chip set no more working. So the whole motherboard should be changed.
Costs nearly 5000INR (80$).

Answer (score -1):

guys if your problem is wifi on your phone and if you do hard reset and still not working, the problem is hardware, the wifi driver. hard reset is the solution for software only not hardware.

Comment: That was already pointed out in [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/78855/16575): "WiFi hardware was faulty". Apart from that, don't confuse [hard-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-reset/info) with [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info). Hard-Reset is only a solution to "switch your device off" if that can't be accomplished by other means ;)